# What is it, and do I have to increase the allocated space for /dev/sda1?

Tags: partitioning

I'm pretty new in managing space in Ubuntu.

I attached the screenshot of system monitor from my PC.

What does `/dev/sda1` is related to ? I see the space alloted to it by default is very less. Is there a way I can increase the space for that partition to avoid any problems in future?

[image: volume usage screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sda1` is your boot partition, you don't have to increase it. Your main partition is `/dev/mapper/...` and that's lots of space, but in case you need more space you can another HDD and increase the size of it using LVM since you have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `/dev/sda1` is your `boot` partition, the primary partition that contains the boot loader.

To increase space in `boot` you need to shrink another partition and free space. Use `gparted` tool on the live cd to do this but please, always backup your data. On `gparted` decrease the size of `/` and then increase the size of boot. Try following this guide: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Alternatively, you can free space on `/boot` following this guide here:

[How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)